# How to display custom validation error message

Tags: json, angular, typescript, validation, angular-forms

For my form it has just one input and that's a text area, where the user enters in JSON Code and if the Text is not Valid JSON it should display an error message but for some reason it wont work.

**Here's my custom validator:**

```js
import { AbstractControl, ValidationErrors, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';

export function jsonValidator(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
  try {
    JSON.parse(control.value);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Not Valid JSON");
    return { jsonInvalid: true };
  }

  return null;
};
```

**Here is the .ts File**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { jsonValidator } from 'src/app/Validators/jsonValid';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-email-body-editor',
  templateUrl: './email-body-editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./email-body-editor.component.scss']
})
export class EmailBodyEditorComponent implements OnInit {

  errorMsg : string = "Not VALID JSON";

  form = this.fb.group({
    jsonField: [null, [Validators.required , jsonValidator]]

  });

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  }

  submit(): void {
    console.log(this.form);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }   
}
```

**And Finally the HTML File**

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="submit()">

    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">

        <mat-label>Textarea</mat-label>
        <textarea matInput
            formControlName="jsonField" 
            cols="1000" 
            placeholder="my custom json here" 
            cdkTextareaAutosize 
            cdkAutosizeMinRows="10"
            cdkAutosizeMaxRows="50">
        </textarea>
    </mat-form-field>
    <br>

    <div *ngIf="form.controls.jsonField.hasError('jsonValidator')">
        {{errorMsg}} 
    </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your validation error name is `jsonInvalid`, not `jsonValidator`.

The name is defined by the return statement in your validator function.

```js
return { jsonInvalid: true };
```

You should use this in your HTML:

```html
<div *ngIf="form.controls.jsonField.hasError('jsonInvalid')">
  {{errorMsg}} 
</div>
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h89jju

Comment: Mate, your a legend i've been stuck on that for a while

Comment: No problem, Mr Code :)

Comment: Btw, the way I debugged this was to display the actual json in the HTML. `<pre>{{form.controls.jsonField.errors | json}}</pre>`

Comment: Ah that's very clever I like that thanks a'lot for taking the time I really appreciate it